# jQuery function only fires once

Tags: jquery

```
function dowork() { 
    $("div#TestPart select option[value^=HMT]").addClass("wrappedElement"); 
} 

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lstDepartment.Attributes.Add("onchange","return dowork();");
}
```

`dowork` is my javascript function which fires on list box item click, but when I click first time it fires normally, but it doesn't fire when I click a second time on the list item.

I don't understand what the problem is. Please help me and thanks in advance for your advice.

```
    *<div id="sidebar"> 
     </div>
    <div id="main">
    <div id="header">
        <asp:Label ID="lblPackageName" runat="server" Text="Package Name"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPackageName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Sex"></asp:Label>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>--Select--</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Both</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
   </div>
    <div id="DepPart"> 
        <asp:ListBox ID="lstDepartment" runat="server" 
            onselectedindexchanged="lstDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            AutoPostBack="True"></asp:ListBox>
      </div>
      <div id="TestPart">
          <asp:ListBox ID="lstTest" runat="server" 
              onselectedindexchanged="lstTest_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True"> </asp:ListBox>
      </div>
       <div id="SubTestPart">
          <asp:ListBox ID="lstSubTest" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
      </div>
       <div id="SelectedTestPart">

<asp:ListBox ID="lstSelectedTest" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
      </div> 
     </div>*




  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function dowork()
{
   $("div#TestPart select option[value^=HMT]").addClass("wrappedElement");
}

</script>
```

Comment: Show your HTML and JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

you may add "alert()" or "console.log()" to your dowork function, to see if the handler does not work or just function. You can also open browser console and type dowork() to launch it manualy and see if that's what you need. Maybe there is something wrong with adding the same class to the same element multiple time? it's hard to tell without rest of the code.

It's shooting blind, but maybe after 2nd launch of dowork() there is no element left without this class WrappedElement? Is that what you want? Maybe you should delete that class:

`$(".wrappedElement").removeClass("wrappedElement");`

Comment: Szamanm so ggo my freind, it is right, a lots of thanks to you